# Can't encrypt inner most file

Tags: python

Folder structure:

```
                       Folder
                        /  \
                       /    \
                subfolder1   files
                    /\         
                   /  \         
    inner_subfolder1   files
                /\
               /  \
sub_inner_folder   files
            /
        files
```

Problem here is files in `sub_inner_folder` are not encrypted.

```
def encypt_Files():
    for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('/home/username/Desktop/folder'):

        for subfolder in subfolders:
            
            os.chdir(folder)
            
            for files in os.listdir():
                
                if files.endswith('.pdf'):
                    
                    PdfReaderobj = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(files, 'rb'))
                    PdfWriterobj = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                    if PdfReaderobj.isEncrypted:
                        break
                    else:
                        PdfWriterobj.addPage(PdfReaderobj.getPage(0))
                        PdfWriterobj.encrypt(sys.argv[1])
                        
                        resultPdf = open(files.strip('.pdf')+'_encrypted.pdf', 'wb')
                        PdfWriterobj.write(resultPdf)
                        resultPdf.close()
```

Comment: why not use the files iterator provided by os.walk? instead of making a new one?

Comment: By files iterator in os.walk() we get files present in all subfolders and folders whereas, what we require here is files present in current directory.

Answer (score 1):

> probem here is files in sub_inner_folder are not encrypted.

You do `os.chdir(folder)` where is should be `os.chdir(subfolder)`. Also, you need to change the directory back using `os.chdir("..")` when you're done with that directory.

If you start on the wrong working directory, you won't be able to `chdir()` anywhere. So you need a `os.chdir("/home/username/Desktop/folder")` first.

Also, permission may break out of the loop. Add

```
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass  # or whatever
except PermissionError:
    pass  # or whatever
```

But: `os.walk()` already gives you a list of files. You should just need to loop over these. That way you also get rid of `os.listdir()`

Yet another option which sounds totally reasonable to me:

```
import glob
for result in glob.iglob('/home/username/Desktop/folder/**/*.pdf'):
    print(result)
```

Comment: Os.chdir(subfolder) will start checking files present in subfolder and ignore files which are present in folder.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is that you're `break`ing out of the inner `for` loop on finding an encrypted file. That should probably be a `continue`, but your making a new iterator using `files` suggests you may need to rethink the whole strategy.

And another problem is that you're `chdir`ing to a relative path that may no longer be relative to *where you are*. I suggest using os.path.join instead.

Oh, and you're `chdir`ing to `folder` instead of to the presumably intended `subfolder`.

I suggest you start over. Use the `files` iterator provided by `os.walk`, and use `os.path.join` to list out the full path to each file in the directory structure. Then add your pdf encryption code using the full path to each file, and ditch `chdir`.

Answer (score 0):

foldername=[]  # used to store folder paths

for folders,subfolders,files in os.walk(path):
foldername.append(folders)   # storing folder paths in list

for file_path in foldername:

```
os.chdir(file_path)  # changing directory path from stored folder paths

for files in os.listdir():
    
    if files.endswith('.pdf'):
        pdfReaderobj=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(files,'rb'))
        pdfWriterobj=PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        
        
        if pdfReaderobj.isEncrypted:
            continue
        else:
            pdfWriterobj.addPage(pdfReaderobj.getPage(0))
            pdfWriterobj.encrypt(sys.argv[1])
            
            resultPdf=open(files.strip('.pdf')+'_encrypted.pdf','wb')
            pdfWriterobj.write(resultPdf)
            resultPdf.close()
```